# How to cancel epic to avoid multiple instances

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable, rxjs6

I've got following epic (btw. [why epic](http://thebestpageintheuniverse.net/c.cgi?u=epic)?)

```
const fetchOrders = action$ => {
  console.log('fetchOrders', action$);
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_ORDERS),
    mergeMap(action => interval(2000).pipe(
      map(_ => ordersReceived(mockOrders()))
    ))
  );
};
```

where `ordersReceived` is an action creator meant to be run with paylod, `mockOrders` returns some mocked payload.

When I call `FETCH_ORDERS` action this epic starts then every 2seconds `ordersReceived` is dispatched and that's fine. But when I've fired this action again I've noticed that the ordersReceived being called more frequent, obviuosly I have created multiple instances that now fire separate actions. Now, is there a way that I could cancel previous epic call?

*Edit*
I've found in the [docs about cancellation](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html) that I have to use another action that the epic will react e.g.

```
const fetchOrders = (action$, state) => {
  console.log('fetchOrders', state);
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_ORDERS),
    mergeMap(action => interval(2001).pipe(
      map(_ => ordersReceived(cloneOrders())),


      takeUntil(action$.pipe(
        filter(action => action.type === FETCH_ORDERS_CANCELLED)
      ))


    ))
  );
};
```

then somewhere call `dispatch({type:FETCH_ORDERS_CANCELLED})`.

It is fine but I was thinking something more autononymous:) so the call to `fetchOrders` will stop anything previously called.

Comment: Can you try with a `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) is what you're looking for. it will cancel the previous observable and emit the values of the new one.

```
const fetchOrders = action$ => {
  console.log('fetchOrders', action$);
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_ORDERS),
    switchMap(action => interval(2000).pipe(
      map(_ => ordersReceived(mockOrders()))
    ))
  );
};
```